# How can I escape a sequence of HTML so it can go inside a tags title attribute?

Tags: html, escaping, tooltip

I've been working on this for way too long. I'm trying to put HTML inside the `title` attribute of a tag. This is for a tooltip. Of course, if this is going to be possible, then I have to escape all of the necessary characters so it doesn't screw up the tag in which it is contained. To be specific, how can I fit the following inside the title attribute of a tag:

```
<a href="test">test</a>
```

That is, I want this:

```
<div title="<a href="test">test</a>">my div</div>
```

I feel like I've tried everything. Is this even possible?

Comment: You have to use some other plugin for clickable hover tooltip effect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled HTML Escape Characters and found a tool to do it: http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/quick-escape/default.php
It produced this string which you can use:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;test&quot;&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed a jQuery-free solution. This was it.

Comment: How is this helpful? This isn't HTML its text.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery you can do it like this

```
$('div').attr('title','<a href="test">test</a>');
```

if you want to escape html tags then you simply can do this

if your test is in a div something like this

```
<div id="tag"><a href="test">test</a></div>
```

then you can do `$('div').attr('title', $("#tag").text());`